# Abelian Group: Basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces

Given an abelian group $G$.

Generating Set:
$$S\subseteq G:\quad\langle S\rangle=G$$

Independent Set:
$$S\subseteq G:\quad \sum_{s\in S}z(s)s=0\implies z=0$$

Basis:=Independent Generating Set

My question are now:
A set is minimally generating iff maximally independent?
Do all bases have the same cardinality?

Comment: Every two bases of the same free abelian group have the same cardinality, so the cardinality of a basis forms an invariant of the group known as its rank

Comment: The answers are: no, yes. For more details see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group

Comment: @Crostul It may be "minimal" here means the cardinal, not the set...at least I've found this several times. For example, $\;\Bbb Z=\langle 2,3\rangle\;$ and the set $\;\{2,3\}\;$ is minimal in the sense that no *proper* set $\;X\subset\{2,3\}\;$ generates the whole $\;\Bbb Z\;$ ....yet it is not minimal sizewise as there are generating sets with one unique lement, namely $\;\Bbb Z=\langle 1\rangle=\langle -1\rangle\;$ . Of course, within free abelian groups I'd go with the second option.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Yes exactly that is what I was looking for: Minimal in the collection of generating sets and maximal in the collection of independent sets. Thank you!!! That already shows what issues there appear/what can go wrong. Indeed your example is a minimal generating set but it fails to be independent!

Comment: What is $z(s)$?

Comment: The $z(s)$ are finitely many nonzero integers (ganze 'Z'ahlen). It is meant as a shorthand notation for: $s+\ldots+s+(-s')+\ldots+(-s')+\ldots=zs+z's'+\ldots$